# Android ViewPager inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

I have a ViewPager with three fragments inside of a SwipeRefreshLayout. The problem I'm seeing is that when attempting to swipe between fragments in the ViewPager, sometimes the SwipeRefreshLayout will take over and stop the interaction with the ViewPager. It appears to do so if the gesture for the ViewPager interaction goes vertical even a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few questions on StackOverflow that were somewhat similar to mine, but none of them quite fit comprehensively. Here's my solution.

A custom SwipeRefreshLayout that can toggle its `InterceptTouchEvent`:

```
class ToggleableSwipeRefreshLayout : SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private var isDisabled = false
    private var touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    private var prevX = 0f

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    fun setDisabled(isDisabled: Boolean) {
        this.isDisabled = isDisabled
        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(isDisabled)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (ev.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                val event = MotionEvent.obtain(ev)
                prevX = event.x
                event.recycle()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (isDisabled) { return false }
                val eventX = ev.x
                val xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - prevX)
                if (xDiff > touchSlop) {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }

}
```

And in the Fragment/Activity this is being used in, add an `OnPageChangeListener` to the ViewPager to monitor the scroll state and enable/disable the SwipeRefreshLayout's `InterceptTouchEvent` accordingly:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
        when (state) {
            ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> swipeLayout.setDisabled(true)
            ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> swipeLayout.setDisabled(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) { }
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) { }
})
```

Now it works great!